Save openpyxl workbook to GCP cloud storage
I am currently modifiying an Excel/.xlsx file in Python through openpyxl library.
The Excel file comes from a Google cloud storage bucket.
I can read the file this way :
blob_file = bucket.blob(f"Folder_1/File_1.xlsx")
blob_bytes_file = blob_file.download_as_bytes()

# Reading my file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(blob_bytes_file ))

Now at this stage, I just need to save my file in the same cloud storage location.
However I'm stuck on trying to find a way. Some examples I've tried :
wb.save(blob_file)
# Or
wb.save("gs://Folder_1/File_1.xlsx")

Any ideas how I can directly save to Cloud Storage, the same way I managed to read from it ?
(I would prefer using OpenPyXl and not pandas to write to gs)

Either do what you're doing when loading but in reverse, or use a tempfile-
